# have a list from loop result python

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, for-loop

I want to have a list from the result of a loop for

i have this code

```py
dates=pd.date_range(start='2019-03-04', periods=3).strftime("%Y-%m-%d").tolist()
for i in range(0,len(dates)):
    filenames = ['file.'+dates[i]]
    filenames
```

result :

```
['file.2019-03-04']
['file.2019-03-05']
['file.2019-03-06']
```

while the desired result is:

```
['file.2019-03-04','file.2019-03-05','file.2019-03-06']
```

Comment: A list comprehension is what you are looking for.

Comment: Use list append() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to create an empty list, and at each iteration append the new filename. One way would be:

```
dates = pd.date_range(start='2019-03-04', periods=3).strftime("%Y-%m-%d").tolist()
filenames = []
for date in dates:  # just iterate through the records, no indexing needed
    filenames.append('file.' + date)
```

The more pythonic way is through a list comprehension. To keep it readable, that would be something like:

```
dates = pd.date_range(start='2019-03-04', periods=3).strftime("%Y-%m-%d").tolist()
filenames = ["file." + date for date in dates]
```

Answer (score 3):

A list comprehension is what you are looking for:

```
dates = pd.date_range(start='2019-03-04', periods=3).strftime("%Y-%m-%d").tolist()
['file.'+ date for date in dates]
```

Answer (score 2):

If using python 3.6 or later, use [`f-string`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals) in a list comprehension:

```
[f'file.{date}' for date in dates]
```

[out]

```
['file.2019-03-04', 'file.2019-03-05', 'file.2019-03-06']
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?

```
dates = pd.date_range(start="2019-03-04", periods=3).strftime("%Y-%m-%d").tolist()

["file." + dates[x] for x in range(0, len(dates))]
```